# RxJS issue premature assignment before emit

Tags: angular, rxjs

My issue is the following. this.version gets the value for the case ?? assigned. The reason is, the .map is not finished by the time of assigment so the check after this.version sees the initial value. Is there any way, to change the script so that the assignment happens once the emit/map has been done? The function getVersionValues is being called in the app.component.ts before the emit/map happens. I have provided the full app.component.ts as well. Please tell me, what else you need for the code to be checked.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { VersionValues } from '@app-core/models/standard-filter.model';
import {ApiHelperService} from "@app-core/services/api-helper.service";
import {UserService} from "@app-core/services/utils/user.service";
import {map, tap} from "rxjs";
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class VersionInfoService {
  versions: Array<string> | undefined  = [];
  userInfo$ = this.apiHelperService.getUserInfo().pipe(map(e => {
    this.versions = e.versions;
    return e;
  }));
  constructor(
    private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService){
  }
  getVersionValues(
    frontendVersion = this.versions?.[0] ?? "1.1.3",
    backendVersion = this.versions?.[1] ?? "1.1.3",
    javaVersion = this.versions?.[2] ?? "1.1.29",
    pentahoVersion =  this.versions?.[3] ?? "1.1.3"
  ): VersionValues {
    this.userInfo$.subscribe((userInfo) => {
      console.log("User Info received:", userInfo);
      console.log("List of versions:" + this.versions?.[0] ?? "1.1.3");
    });
    return {
      frontendVersion,
      backendVersion,
      pentahoVersion,
      javaVersion
    };
  }
}
```

And here where it is called:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Type} from '@angular/core';
import {SmartSafeAny} from '@r-software/smart-ng/core/types';
import {
  BaseSlotComponent,
  BaseSlotInfoInputType,
  SmartBaseButton,
  SmartButtonSlotItem,
  SmartHeaderService,
  SmartSidebarNavigationService,
  SmartSlotItem
} from '@r-software/smart-ng/layout';
import {filter, takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {
  SmartHeaderBaseSlotButtonComponent
} from '@app-core/components/smart-header-base-slot-button/smart-header-base-slot-button.component';
import {SmartDialog} from '@r-software/smart-ng/dialog';
import {AccessModalComponent} from '@app-shared/components/access-modal/access-modal.component';
import {ApiHelperService} from '@app-core/services/api-helper.service';
import {SidebarHelperService} from '@app-core/services/utils/sidebar-helper.service';
import {ConfigurationService} from '@app-core/services/configuration/configuration.service';
import {SpotviewerUiWebMetaDataService} from 'meta-data/spotviewer-ui-web-meta-data.service';
import {FeatureStateService} from '@app-core/services/utils/feature-state.service';
import {ClassEnum} from '@app-core/models/enum/class.enum';
import {VersionInfoService} from "@app-core/services/utils/version-info.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  get slotItems(): SmartSlotItem {
    return this._slotItems;
  }

  set slotItems(value: SmartSlotItem) {
    this._slotItems = value;
  }
  private _slotItems!: SmartSlotItem;
  buttonSlotItems!: SmartButtonSlotItem[];
  private baseButtons: SmartBaseButton[] = this.createBaseButton();
  private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private metaDataService: SpotviewerUiWebMetaDataService,
    private navigationHelperService: SidebarHelperService,
    private sidebarService: SmartSidebarNavigationService,
    private versionInfoService: VersionInfoService,
    private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    private featureStateService: FeatureStateService,
    private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService,
    private headerService: SmartHeaderService,
    private dialog: SmartDialog
  ) {
    this.headerService.setButtonTemplateSlot(this.baseButtons);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.featureStateService.mapFeaturesFromToken();
    this.headerService.setInfoSlot('SPOT');
    this.sidebarService.register([]);
    this.getReportTypes();
    const [textTemplate$, _textOnly$, buttons$]: Observable<SmartSafeAny>[] = this.headerService.__slotSource__;

    textTemplate$
      .pipe(
        filter((slot) => !!slot),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (slot: [Type<BaseSlotComponent>, BaseSlotInfoInputType]) => {
          const [component, data] = slot;
          this._slotItems = new SmartSlotItem(component, data);
        }
      });

    buttons$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe({
      next: (slots: SmartBaseButton[]) => {
        this.buttonSlotItems = slots.map((entry) => new SmartButtonSlotItem(SmartHeaderBaseSlotButtonComponent, entry));
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.featureStateService.state.bigScrollbar) {
      const smartSidenavEl = document.querySelector('smart-sidenav');
      const scrollEl = document.querySelector('.content-container');
      if (smartSidenavEl && scrollEl) {
        smartSidenavEl.className += ClassEnum.BIG_SCROLLBAR;
        scrollEl.className += ClassEnum.BIG_SCROLLBAR;
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  private getReportTypes(): void {
    this.navigationHelperService.sidebar$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(e => {
        this.sidebarService.addEntry(e);
      })
  }

  private createBaseButton(): SmartBaseButton[] {
    //const fe_version = `FEv${this.metaDataService.getMetaData().version.split('-')[0]}`;
    const fe_version = `FEv${this.versionInfoService.getVersionValues().frontendVersion}`;
    const be_version = `BEv${this.versionInfoService.getVersionValues().backendVersion}`;
    const ja_version = `JAv${this.versionInfoService.getVersionValues().javaVersion}`;
    const pe_version = `PEv${this.versionInfoService.getVersionValues().pentahoVersion}`;

    return [
      {
        text: ja_version+"|"+pe_version+"|"+be_version+"|"+fe_version,
        type: 'version',
        callback: () => {
          // this is intentional
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Befugnis',
        icon: 'key',
        primary: true,
        callback: () => {
          this.dialog.open(AccessModalComponent, {
            width: '800px',
            minHeight: '500px'
          });
        }
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: please share a simplified working stackblitz highlighting the issue

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? Everything is important there, I guess.

Comment: No, you are calling getVersionValues somewhere else and you are asking how its not  working when you have not shared the places where the two separate things are getting called, if you provide the stackblitz with the issue replicated, we will know exactly how your application is setup, the entire code is not required, just the minimal reproducible code where the issue occours!

Comment: Ok, changed it, hope it helps.

Comment: require a working stackblitz where the issue happens! this code is too minimal!

Comment: Please tell me what is missing, I can hardly copy the whole project here.

Comment: this is more than enough, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getVersionValues()` should return an Observable based on `userInfo$`:

```ts
getVersionValues(frontendVersion?: string, backendVersion?: string, javaVersion?: string, pentahoVersion?: string): Observable<VersionValues> {
  return this.userInfo$.pipe(
    tap((defaults) => {
      frontendVersion ??= defaults[0];
      backendVersion ??= defaults[1];
      pentahoVersion ??= defaults[2];
      javaVersion ??= defaults[3];
    }),
    map(() => ({
      frontendVersion,
      backendVersion,
      pentahoVersion,
      javaVersion
    }));
}
```

Comment: The the defaults part is underlined, because it is set as type UserResult which has no index, since it is not an array, but an object.

Comment: It's used as an array in the above code, so I did it the same way here.

Comment: No, version is an array, that is true, because it is an array in the user, or in this case UserResult object. But UserResult to which default is typed is an object. I can copy you the error screenshot if you want.
So the .map operation does extract the array from the object, only then it is an array.